# ax.text using combined transData and transAxes for (x,y)

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, transform

I'm trying to print a set of lines in the same figure, and write on top of the axis, above each line, some text. I use the minimum value of x of each set of data as a position of the text. The code looks like

```
for i in range(jobs):
  ax.text(xmin,1.15, nameid, rotation=45, ha='left', fontsize=tinyfont, color='k', va='center')
```

When I do something like that, the text is printed - but in the middle of the graph (as it's using the data coordinates):
[image: text being printed in the wrong position]

As I want to print above the axis, I use then `transform=ax.transAxes` to print above, as

```
for i in range(jobs):
  ax.text(xmin,1.15, nameid, transform=ax.transAxes, rotation=45, ha='left', fontsize=tinyfont, color='k', va='center')
```

Although the text move to the correct position, only the first one is being written:
[image: only first text being printed in the correct position]

edit: This happens because the position is above the axis limit 1.0. So, for the x position, I'd like to use the data value xmin; For the y, I want a fixed position above the axis. The problem is that I don't know the final x_lim and y_lim beforehand, as I loop over the data and plot the different pieces.

How can I add the text using the x of the data, but in a constant "y" above the axis?

Comment: what about using data coordinates with something like: `ax.text(xmin, ax.get_ylim()[1], ...)`. You might need to add a small offset to make it look nice.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the final y_lim beforehand; I read a lot of data, plot the first piece (including the text), then go to the next.

Comment: I have edited the text to explain better this point. I think the solution is to use some combination of transData for x and transAxes for y (so I edited the title), but I was not able to do this.

Comment: I see. My answer below should do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a "blended transform", where you use data coordinates for the x axis and axes coordinate for the y axis. This is documented here:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations

A simple example would be:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

# code to plot, and find xmin, etc...

ax.text(xmin, 1.15, nameid, rotation=45, ha='left', fontsize=tinyfont,
        color='k', va='center', transform=trans)
```

Note that on the documentation site, it mentions a shortcut:

> The blended transformations where x is in data coords and y in axes coordinates is so useful that we have helper methods to return the versions Matplotlib uses internally for drawing ticks, ticklabels, etc. The methods are `matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform()` and `matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yaxis_transform()`. So in the example above, the call to `blended_transform_factory()` can be replaced by `get_xaxis_transform`:
>
> ```
> trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()
> ```

So, you could just use:

```
ax.text(xmin, 1.15, nameid, rotation=45, ha='left', fontsize=tinyfont,
        color='k', va='center', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```